# How to retrieve UIElement by uid?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

In a test case I would like to check whether a `StackPanel` is visible.

All the answers I've found for this assume you already have the UIElement object.

So how do I get my `StackPanel` via it's `uid`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using code behind approach or mvvm? You can check the Visibility by adding `Name` to `StackPanel` and refer to it directly from code behind:

```
var stackPanelVisibility = StackPanelName.Visibility;
```

Or, with mvvm approach, you can bind a `Visibility` of the `StackPanel` to property of type `Visibility` in viewmodel:

xaml:

```
<StackPanel Visibility={Binding StackPanelVisibility} />
```

viewmodel:

```
Visibility StackPanelVisibility 
{
     get
     { //...
     }
     set
     { //...
     }
}
```

Comment: Hm, I think the project uses a bit of both.  Cool, that makes sense.  I guess this won't be accessible from a unit test?

Comment: It won' be. There is a way to test UI on Windows Phone with Coded UI Tests: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn747198.aspx, but I didn't try it.

Comment: Ah, awesome.  Thanks a lot marcinax!